# replace $_SESSION superglobal with $SESSION

Tags: moodle

do we still have to replace $_SESSION php superglobal by Moodle global called $SESSION or not ?

```
$_SESSION -> $SESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't be "replacing" / overwriting the $_SESSION global with the value of $SESSION, because that would wipe out a whole lot of data used by Moodle.

If your question is, should be be *using* $SESSION in Moodle, instead of the PHP $_SESSION superglobal, then the answer is definitely yes (because Moodle is using $_SESSION and you don't want to be getting in the way of that).